# Retrieve a list of country names using Google places api

Tags: google-places-api

How can we get a list of countries/stats/cities in the world using Google places API? Using either google api javascript library or google api web service interface.

Comment: Could someone explain why this question got a down vote? can we remove the down vote because there have been clearly interests and answers to this question?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't believe that's allowed under the license terms of the Google Places API.

Instead, I suggest using http://geonames.org.  Their data is updated very frequently and is licensed under a Creative Commons attribution license:
http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/

For country names & stats, the file is located here:
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt

All available downloads are here:
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

So, to get the list of all *places* within a country that you requested, just fetch the zip file with the 2-letter ISO country code.  For example, to get all *places* within the United States, fetch this file:
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/US.zip

Once fetched, you further have to filter the list in order to only get the cities.

Alternatively, if you're ok with just cities with population > 1000, use this file:
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities1000.zip

In fact, I recommend the 2nd approach, because *all* cities can be a very big list.

For more info and a list of all the files available:
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt

Good luck on your project!

Comment: With geonames.org, it has published api for retrieving list of country names and state names for each country; then there is the api for retrieving all cities in the world. But If you want to retrieve a list of cities within a particular state/province, there is no dedicated api for it.

Answer (score 12):

**Updated on 29 Jan 2022**

For the **country list** and it's full detail download json file form this link. and use it in your project `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VBsGFi20SHElkQp82LP0EwZGEzQMQjWc/view`.

Its free for use

Comment: This is down today, bringing our production app down with it.

Let this be a teaching moment- Don't rely on 3rd parties to do this. Maintain your own simple lists and update when you need to.

Comment: sorry for that. I update my answer. now you can download it and use it in your project. @ChrisFremgen thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The following opensource project looks a good fit nowadays:

https://restcountries.com/

Documentation looks very clear and performance looks reasonable.